# div content display on a textbox HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the content of one of my `div` in a textbox ... Can somebody help me out with this? How can I display the content of my `div` `tag` in a textbox in HTML?

The following is what I have tried so far:

```js
  <script>
    var test = document.getElementById("div").innerHtml;
    document.getElementById("Key").value = test;
    </script>
```

```html
    <div id="div" style="width: 50px" /></div>   
    <input type="text" id="Key" style="width: 50px" />
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. here we expect you to have a go first, and show us what you've done (even if it's broken). Then we can help you figure out the bit that doesn't work. If you're not sure how to start - try googling for a tutorial first.

Comment: I have used getelementbyid and here is what i've done so far`code` <script>
 var test = "Hello";
document.getElementById("storageKey").value = test;</script>`code`

Comment: @JuliusEricTuliao As I suggested in the other question you posted a few minutes ago, click here and read how to ask questions on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Julius - you actually have to edit your question, and put in all the relevant code. Hearing a description of the kinds of things you used is not enough for us to figure out what you actually did. Show us what you actually did (in your question, not the comments).

Comment: @TarynEast you are so much more patient than I am.  Maybe that means I'm getting old

Comment: @JuliusEricTuliao that small piece of javascript isn't enough. Please display **all** relevant source code, this includes the html that relates to your question and javascript function.

Comment: @JuliusEricTuliao don't post what you've done in a comment, edit (update) your answer by showing HTML and JS.  Look at other questions in the category if you need help in seeing what a good question looks like

Comment: Im very sorry ...it's my first time asking in stackoverflow...

Comment: @vol7ron haha - I've found myself getting more patient as I get older... each to their own, I guess ;)

Comment: @JuliusEricTuliao - firstly `div` is a really bad name for an id - give it something meaningful. Secondly - do you see the `\` inside the opening div tag? that means you've just closed the div... `<div id="div" style="width: 50px" />` is the same as `<div id="div" style="width: 50px" /></div> ` so your code is now `<div id="div" style="width: 50px" /></div></div>` and *nothing* in between the `<div id="div" style="width: 50px" />` and `</div> will count as the inner html

Comment: I actually got it wrong... but yeah will transfer to an answer now.

Comment: @vol7ron Not any more... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Julius, in your code, the text part needs to be a div class and in an external css stylesheet; declare the div class with a border.
Example HTML :

```
<div class="boxed">
  This text is enclosed in a box.
</div>
CSS :
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid green ;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Julius Eric Tuliao is asking for... " display the content of one of my div `in a textbox`"

Comment: that's not what i'm looking for...but thank you still.. what i want to ask is how to display the text of my div in a textbox not putting the textbox inside my div

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a div:

```js
var myTextBox = $("#myTextBox");
var myText = $(".myDiv").text();

myTextBox.val(myText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"> blah blah </div>
<input type="text" value="" id="myTextBox" />
```

Using JQuery, you can do:

```
var myText = $(".myDiv").text(); // query the DOM for .myDiv selector and get its text
var myTextBox = $("#myTextBox"); // query the DOM and get your textbox
myTextBox.val(myText); // assign value to your textbox
```

To use jquery, you have to include it at the top of your html page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to show Julius Eric Tuliao how to link jQuery since jQuery isn't tagged. This could be due to not knowing how to use it. Comments in the source code will also help people understand what the code is doing rather than a copy/paste and hope it all works. The idea is to learn and understand the answers, not just take the source code.

Comment: @gone43v3r  i can't figured it out i've tried your code but still it does'nt work for me..have you tried it already?

Comment: A programmer should not learn jQuery until they have a foundation in JavaScript, it's not a good idea to suggest they use it too early.

Comment: well they can't learn if you will not introduce it. Anyways, just trying to help here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have a div class outside the form code and with css style the div and form

```
<div id="div">
    <form id="form">
        <input id="text" type="textbox" />
    </form>
</div>
#div {
    text-align: center;
}
#text {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the content from the div once the page had loaded.

> **If** you have dynamic data: You can put this into a function and have `window.onload` call that function. If you want the content to update with the dynamic data then you can call the function to update the text box.

```js
window.onload=function(){
//Get the innerHTML of the div tag
 var a=document.getElementById('div').innerHTML;
//Place the inner HTML into the text box 'Key'
 document.getElementById('Key').value=a;
};
```

```html
<div id="div" style="width:50px;">Content here...</div>
<input type="text" id="Key"/>
```

I hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly div is a really bad name for an id - give it something meaningful.

Secondly - do you see the `/` inside the opening div tag? that means you've just closed the div...

`<div id="div" style="width: 50px" />` 
is the same as 
`<div id="div" style="width: 50px" /></div>` so your code is now

`<div id="div" style="width: 50px"></div></div>`

and nothing in between the 
`<div id="div" style="width: 50px" />` and `</div>` will count as the inner html